# Does Deno have a window object

Tags: deno

Deno claims to be browser-compatible. Does that mean it has a window / navigator object and what would that mean in terms of things like setting window.location?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The global object in Deno is currently just called `window` (and `globalThis` due to upcoming ES standards, sadly). There is currently no `navigator`/`window.location` implemented.

The browser-compatible aspects of Deno are aiming to parts that are reasonable to exist even without under the browser environment, e.g. `Event`, `TextEncoder`, `fetch`, etc. It would be an unnecessary burden to implement things like the complete DOM in the Deno core, and such tasks should be delegated to third-party modules (like JSDOM if ported to Deno)

**Update**: `window.location` is added in Deno v0.3.0, pointing to the entry file's path (remote or local) (see usage in https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1750 , could be useful to implement something similar to Python's `if __name__ == "__main__"`

Comment: `window.location` was removed before 1.0: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3520

Comment: having `window` object in server-side seems weird.